# How to choose only the "male" attribute from a newly compiled dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the following dataframe which I created from a much larger csv file with additional information in columns not needed:

df_avg_tot_purch = df_purchase_data.groupby(["SN", "Gender"])["Price"].agg(lambda x: x.unique().mean())
df_avg_tot_purch.head()

This code results in the following:

> SN            Gender
> Adairialis76  Male      2.28
> Adastirin33   Female    4.48
> Aeda94        Male      4.91
> Aela59        Male      4.32
> Aelaria33     Male      1.79
> Name: Price, dtype: float64

I now need to have this dataframe only show the male gender. The point of the project here is to find all the individuals (which may repeat in the rows), determine the average of each of their purchases. I did it this way because I also need to run another for females and "others" in the column.

Comment: df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch['Gender'] == 'Male']

Comment: Hi Marcin,

Thank you for your help! I tried this code, or something similar, and it gives an error. It's long and probably much of this is unnecessary but it throws this at me:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1496             try:
-> 1497                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, k)
   1498             except IndexError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

Comment: pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-61b28377d911> in <module>
      3 df_avg_tot_purch = df_purchase_data.groupby(["SN", "Gender"])["Price"].agg(lambda x: x.unique().mean())
      4 df_avg_tot_purch.head()
----> 5 df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch['Gender'] == 'Male']
      6 
      7 #df_male_ind_tot_avg = df_avg_tot_purch.loc[df_avg_tot_purch["Gender"] == "Male"]

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1503                     raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   1504                 else:
-> 1505                     raise e1
   1506             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   1507                 raise e1

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1487 
   1488         try:
-> 1489             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1490         except KeyError as e1:
   1491             try:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: 'Gender'

Comment: oh, my bad, how about this?
df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch.index.isin(['Male'], level='Gender')]

Comment: or do:
df_avg_tot_purch = df_avg_tot_purch.reset_index()


df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch['Gender'] == 'Male']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after groupby the keys on which you grouped become indices, so now you have to either reset index to change them into normal columns, or explicitly use index while subsetting

```
df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch.index.isin(['Male'], level='Gender')]
```

or

```
df_avg_tot_purch = df_avg_tot_purch.reset_index()
df_avg_tot_purch[df_avg_tot_purch['Gender'] == 'Male']
```

Comment: Marcin - FANTASTIC! The first line there worked in this situation. Not sure why the other one did. Thank you so much!